# function php not show result from two queries

Tags: mysql, function, pdo, global

I try write a function. Its put `$row->idf` value from first select query to second select query and show sum of `zaloha` for each idf, but if I want to use `$row->idf` for show name of it show nothig. If I write only queries without function its working. Why? Thanks

```
<?php
function zalBoss () {
    global $conn;

    $fir = 'SELECT * FROM firma WHERE faktiv = 1';
    $res = $conn->query($fir);

    while ($row = $res->fetchObject()) {

        $quer = 'SELECT SUM(zaloha) AS zaloha FROM obchody WHERE firma = '.$row->idf.' AND stav = 2';
        $result = $conn->query($quer);
        $rw = $result->fetchObject();

        echo $firma_array[$row->idf].': '.$rw->zaloha.'<br>';
    }
}

zalBoss();
?>
```

EDIT:
$firma_array is included with file `include('obr/sel.php');`

```
$firma_array = array();
$tdb = 'SELECT * FROM firma ORDER BY idf';
    $vysl3 = $conn->query($tdb);
    while ($riadok1 = $vysl3->fetchObject())
    {
    $firma_array[$riadok1->idf]=$riadok1->fmenoskr;
    }
```

Comment: where's `$firma_array` defined?

Comment: its included `include('obr/sel.php');`

Comment: @mpen I edited post, can you help me?

Comment: You don't pass `$firma_array` to the function, or set it as `global` inside the function

Comment: @AlonEitan thanks now I understand....but is that way how define globals in one file and use in any function ?

Comment: @Stanley01 If you want to use it in any function than you just need to define it as global afaik (But with a bit more context we might be able to suggest better alternatives)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.